# jQuery - POSTing contents of file on server to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a very basic dynamic jQuery search function which queries a json array:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #result {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   max-width:870px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 400px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1001;
  }
  .link-class:hover{
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h3 align="center">Search ...</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search ..." class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });
 
 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $.post("https://123.xyz/endpoint",
    
    -- payload here ---
    
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
   
 });
});

</script>
```

The json array stores objects in the following format:

```
{
    "name":"Apples",
    "image": "images/apples.jpg",
    "location":"Depot 1, 12",
    "path":"https://123.xyz/data/343r.xml"
  },
  {
    "name":"Oranges",
    "image": "images/oranges.jpg",
    "location":"Depot 1, 13"
    "path":"https://123.xyz/data/331r.xml"
  },
```

The "path" object in the array represents the physcial location of a file on the server.

When a user searches, and click the relevant info, I'd like a function to post the contents of a flat file on the server to another endpoint on the server (i.e. pass XML file --> https://123.xyz/endpoint).

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.  I can post json formatted data, but I don't know how to pass the string of a flat file that alreadt exists on the server (not using an upload function) from one location to another.

The files are XML data - it's a bit resource intensive but could they be read into another variable and then POSTed as a string to the endpoint?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to pass the contents of the file on the server to another endpoint on the server. Just tell the server the name of the file and the server can lookup the file content.

Comment: Thanks Bryn.  The endpoint (on the same server) processes certain files that are posted to it from a client's browser.   I wanted a way to POST the contents of the file based on its local path.  At the moment, all I seem to be doing is posting the path to server rather then the full file contents.

Comment: I'm confused by "post the contents of a flat file on the server to another endpoint on the server". Do you mean "post the contents of a flat file on the _client to an endpoint on the server" ? If you want to get the contents of a file from a client, the user must upload the file using a <input type="file" /> control. This can not be done programmatically (even if you know the filename), because security.

Comment: Hi Bryn, no, it really is a flat file on the server. A client searches using the jquery, one of the elements in the json array is a path on the server. The clients selects what they want, so for example Oranges. From there, I want the contents of the file /data/331r.xml to be posted to /endpoint.php - that's the part I can't get my head around. In my tests, I've been able to post the uri which doesn't do anything as my endpoint is expecting an xml file.   There must be a more logical way if doing this than "uploading" a file that already exists on the server.

Comment: If the file is on the server, why can't the server just read the file? ie, change your endpoint so it expects a filename to be read, rather than XML to be processed.